MySQL 8. 0 does not perform query from Bash if Bash run by PHP
Environment - Almalinux 9 latest, Apache/2.4.57, MySQL 8.0.36, PHP 7.4.33 - PHP test file - phpbash.php
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
shell_exec("sh /d/phpbash.sh") ;
echo "DONE" ;
?>

Bash test file
#!/bin/bash

mysql -uroot -e 'SELECT id, programid FROM data.call'  >> /d/testoutput.txt ;

printf 'SELECT id, programid FROM data.call\n'  >> /d/testoutput.txt ;

exit ;
    sh

Problem description
When run from shell - sh /d/phpbash.sh - both commands has performed.
When run from browser PHPBASH.PHP - only PRINTF command has performed, MySQL SELECT ignored.
As PRINTF works - it means that all permissions are enough to perform BASH started by PHP.
Enabled full log for MySQL - such a query even NOT arised there, so that even not passed from bash.
ERGO - under MySQL 8 I can't pass query from BASH to MySQL if BASH run by PHP.
(By the way, same script on another server works under same environment but CentOS 7 and MySQL 5.5 version)
May be a "secret setting" should be added to MySQL 8 config to allow such a query? Or something specific from Apache?

Maybe mysql as command is not reachable from the environment provided through php (e.g. $PATH, alias or functions…). What happens if you run the PHP file with the php cli, i.e. also from shell?

Why would you want to run a mysql query through bash from PHP? PHP has database libraries, just use those to run the query directly. This greatly reduces the number of possible points of failure.

I agree with the others, you should use the PHP libraries. However, a possibility is that you're not passing in a password for the root mysql user. It probably has a password that may live in your user's .my.cnf, but the php script wouldn't have access to it. You really shouldn't be using the root user anyway, as it's a security risk.

@pmf - hm, when run from shell /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/dt/phpbash.php - both BASH queries performed - and what it could mean in comparison with run same PHP from browser ?

Thanks others for comments - but I prefer not discuss safety or ways how to perform queries, because this case I'm interested to find the reason why it does not work.

Did you check whether shell_exec returns any error message? Maybe reduce the bash script to the mysql call and check whether this throws any hint (like: password missing, binary not found, empty result,...)

Yep, check if shell_exec produces any output. Remember that Apache (and therefore the PHP script which is running through the Apache server, and thus the shell session your PHP script creates via shell_exec) runs as a different identity than when you are using the bash script yourself in your terminal. That identity may not have access to the same PATH variables, or any my.cnf file which might be storing your mysql credentials, etc. It may also not have permission to the file you're trying to write to, etc.

Added error_reporting(E_ALL); to php file as above - no any errors shown.

That's because anything the bash shell produces won't be PHP runtime errors - once you transfer control to the shell, the execution is happening outside of PHP's runtime. To PHP they'd just be text which comes back in the output of the shell command. But your PHP code is ignoring what shell_exec returns. As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php the return value of the shell_exec function is the output produced by the shell script

@ADyson - as described above shell_exec produces output from PRINTF command, so everything works. The question is about MySQL query.

Yes but that's only printing the exact thing you told it to print into that file. If the mysql executable returns an error, that would be in the standard output of the shell command, which your PHP code is ignoring.

@ADyson - again, as described I enabled full log of MySQL with max log_error_verbosity=3 - but such a query even not arise there. I suppose if a MySQL error was - it should be written to log.

Is it so difficult to put an echo before shell_exec, and remove everything after the line with the SELECT query from the shell script? Maybe it does not help to spot the problem, but please give it a try

Maybe it's not MySQL itself throwing an error, but the bash script itself

But when I run script directly from CLI - everything works including MySQL query, so no errors in Bash script itself

Well, running something completely different might yield completely different results. Running the same bash script from a shell compared to running it from a PHP script is such a thing: it might use a different user, different environment variables, all that from a different folder. So much moving parts....

ADyson has already explained to you that the environments for running a script in CLI and running a script through Apache are different, and your current code cannot capture the errors generated by sh.

Try this: Find out the user that your webserver runs under (apache, www-data). Then run sudo -u apache sh /d/phpbash.sh and see if that works (replace apache with the web user if it's not apache)

Can you stop arguing with us please, and just capture the shell_exec output? It'll only take you a few seconds to change the PHP script. We're not asking you just to waste your time! Then we can establish whether it's telling us anything useful or not. If it's not, then fine, but at least we've ruled it out. At the moment you seem to be trying to give us reasons not to do that simple debugging step, which really doesn't make a lot of sense.

I suppose if a MySQL error was - it should be written to log...unless perhaps it couldn't even establish a connection in the first place, or couldn't find the mysql executable (for example). That sort of info might not make it to the server log. Again...capture and show the shell_exec output from your PHP script so we can see what, if anything, is going on at that step. The more different sources of information we have, the better - wouldn't you agree?

when I run script directly from CLI - everything works including MySQL query, so no errors in Bash script itself...that's a huge assumption, and one which doesn't fit with the evidence of your own investigations so far - clearly it's not working when executed from PHP. As I said, executing it from PHP is running it under a different identity with consequential differences in the environmental conditions. You cannot assume it will work exactly the same in those circumstances...and indeed it appears not to be. So you need to capture the shell output in order to see better what happens.

@ADyson - if you mean $output=shell_exec("sh /d/phpbash.sh") ; echo "$output"; - it does not echo anything, not in CLI, not in browser. If you mean something else under SHELL OUTPUT - please, explain.

it does not echo anything - can you also use var_dump on $output, to check whether an empty string or anything else was returned?

@NicoHaase - found in Apache error log ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - most of all this is the problem - when run Bash directly - system accepts, but same Bash from PHP - not allowed. So consider how to solve such a task.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This is what others have been speculating for hours: that the password is missing. Essentially, this is not a problem of PHP itself

...and I think anyber's comment from an hour earlier probably explains why that's happening. As you can see, your bash command does not specify the root password. Normally with mysql, if you don't specify the password the system will try to read it from a .cnf file. Do you have one of those for yourself? Please tell us. I'd assume the web user probably doesn't have one.

It's strange that such an error appears in the Apache log though...the shell mysql command isn't really run via Apache. Are you certain it's definitely related? And did you change the PHP to use var_dump() as Nico requested? What was the result when you did that? We will progress a lot faster if you directly answer our enquries rather than telling us about something else (or at least as well as telling us about something else).

Under the configuration mentioned above the problem was found in Apache error_log, not in PHP output:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
password: NO)

because in my case BASH knows where the password for root is located when running from shell directly.
But when run same BASH through PHP, because this is running under a different identity it does not know the location of the .cnf file which contains the password.
As described in
Suppress warning messages using mysql from within Terminal, but password written in bash script
it's possible to explicitly specify the file which should be used, for example:
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/config.cnf -e 'SELECT id, programid FROM data.call'  >> /d/testoutput.txt ;

Then everything works and no warning messages.
